# Install Redmine 3.x on WHM/Cpanel

Tags: cpanel, redmine, centos6, whm

Guys I've spent last 24 hours continuously trying to install Redmine 3.x on the WHM/Cpanel server but failed to do so. Can some please guide me with one proper way or tell me about a relatively new article regarding this issue because every solution i find on the internet is old.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of the box solution for Cpanel.

Redmine is complex Ruby on Rails based web application, and as such it relies on lot's of 3rd party libraries, defined in Gemfile.

Although it migth be possible to install all Gems manually via Cpanel and avoid bundle install command, you would still need to run some commands like

```
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

So to install it via WHM/Cpanel, I suggest you create a cpanel account for your Redmine, then enable SSH access for that Cpanel user, and follow [official installation tutorial from Redmine.](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall) (Which is too big to write here inside  answer).

Just make sure to unpack your Redmine outside public_html!

And you can deploy your Redmine via Cpanel as FastCGI, by pointing your application path to Redmine's public directory, just make sure to have dispatch.fcgi in your public folder of Redmine

```
mv dispatch.fcgi.example dispatch.fcgi
mv htaccess.fcgi.example .htaccess
```